# How to get video tag src using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get video URL using JavaScript.
Code is ...

```
<div class="flideo">
    <video x-webkit-airplay="allow" preload="" src="http://pdl.vimeocdn.com/80388/120/224743790.mp4?token2=1394169786_c1f036dda110a70d45fd824ec6692b94&amp;aksessionid=e766a96a167c751e" poster=""></video>
</div>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var vids = document.getElementsByTagName('video') 
// vids is an HTMLCollection
for( var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++ ){ 
    console.log( vids.item(i).src )
}
```

Seems to work for me!  Note, that turns an HTMLCollection.  `.length` gives the length and `item(i)` gives the item at `i`.

```js
var vids = document.getElementsByTagName('video') 
// vids is an HTMLCollection
for( var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++ ){ 
    console.log( vids.item(i).src )
}
```

```html
<div class="flideo">
    <video x-webkit-airplay="allow" preload="" src="http://pdl.vimeocdn.com/80388/120/224743790.mp4?token2=1394169786_c1f036dda110a70d45fd824ec6692b94&amp;aksessionid=e766a96a167c751e" poster=""></video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, I had to change `src` to `currentSrc`, i.e.:

```
var videoTags = document.getElementsByTagName('video')
 for( var i = 0; i < videoTags.length; i++ ){
      alert( videoTags.item(i).currentSrc )
}
```

Comment: So someone knows what is the difference between **src** and **currentSrc** properties ?

Comment: @Davide according to this page on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/src, the `src` attribute reflects the src attribute of the html element, while `currentSrc` is the current source being used, dependent on some other factors